# Extract positions 2-7 from a fasta sequence for each gene using Bash

Tags: awk, command-line, fasta

I've got a file with a subset of geneIDs in it, and a fasta file with all geneIDs and their sequences. For each gene in the subset file, I want to get positions 2-7 from the start of each fasta sequence. Ideally the output file would be 'pos 2-7' '\t' 'geneID'.

Example subset:

```
mmu-let-7g-5p MIMAT0000121  
mmu-let-7i-5p MIMAT0000122
```

Fasta file:

```
>mmu-let-7g-5p MIMAT0000121 
UGAGGUAGUAGUUUGUACAGUU
>mmu-let-7i-5p MIMAT0000122 
UGAGGUAGUAGUUUGUGCUGUU
>mmu-let-7f-5p MIMAT0000525 
UGAGGUAGUAGAUUGUAUAGUU
```

wanted output:

```
GAGGUA   mmu-let-7g-5p MIMAT0000121
GAGGUA   mmu-let-7i-5p MIMAT0000122
```

The first part (pulling out fasta sequences for the subset of genes) I've done using `grep -w -A 1 -f`. Not sure how to get pos 2-7 and make the output look like that now using Bash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples only in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[$1]=$2
  next
}
/^>/{
  ind=substr($1,2)
}
/^>/ && (ind in a){
  found=1
  val=ind OFS a[ind]
  next
}
found{
  print substr($0,2,6) OFS val
  val=found=""
}
' gene fastafile
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                               ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{                            ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when gene Input_file is being read.
  a[$1]=$2                          ##Creating array a with index of $1 and value of $2 here.
  next                              ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
/^>/{                               ##Checking condition if line starts from > then do following.
  ind=substr($1,2)                  ##Creating ind which has substring from 2nd charcters to all values of first field.
}
/^>/ && (ind in a){                 ##Checking if line starts with > and ind is present in array a then do following.
  found=1                           ##Setting found to 1 here.
  val=ind OFS a[ind]                ##Creating val which has ind OFS and value of a with index of ind.
  next                              ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
found{                              ##Checking condition if found is NOT NULL then do following.
  print substr($0,2,6) OFS val      ##Printing sub string from 2nd to 7th character OFS and val here.
  val=found=""                      ##Nullifying val and found here.
}
' gene fastafile                    ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Answer (score 6):

Tested with `GNU awk`, but I think it will work with any `awk`:

```sh
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]; next}
       $1 in a{print substr($2, 2, 6), $1}
      ' gene.txt RS='>' FS='\n' OFS='\t' fasta.txt
GAGGUA  mmu-let-7g-5p MIMAT0000121
GAGGUA  mmu-let-7i-5p MIMAT0000122
```

- `NR==FNR{a[$0]; next}` build array with each line content as key for the first file passed to `awk`
- `RS='>' FS='\n' OFS='\t'` these will set input record separator to `>`, input field separator to newline and output field separator to tab only for the second file (since these variables are assigned after the first filename)
- `$1 in a{print substr($2, 2, 7), $1}` if first field exists as a key in array `a`, print the required details

If there can be trailing whitespace characters at the end of lines, use:

```sh
$ awk 'NR==FNR{sub(/[[:space:]]+$/, ""); a[$0]; next}
       $1 in a{print substr($2, 2, 6), $1}
      ' gene.txt RS='>' FS='[[:space:]]*\n' OFS='\t' fasta.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Another awk:

```
$ awk '
{
    gsub(/ +$/,"")                 # clean trailing space from sample data 
}
NR==FNR {                          # process subset file as it is smaller
    a[$0]                          # hash keys
    next                        
}                                  # process fasta file
/^>/ && ((p=substr($0,2)) in a) {  # if string found in hash
    if(getline>0)                  # read next record
        print substr($0,2,6),p     # and print
}' subset fasta
```

Output:

```
GAGGUA mmu-let-7g-5p MIMAT0000121
GAGGUA mmu-let-7i-5p MIMAT0000122
```

Comment: You probably want to restrict the last condition to lines starting with `>`. This happens to work as long as there is no whitespace after the `>` but you end up comparing a lot of things needlessly.

Comment: What's _the last condition_, this: `((p=substr($0,2)) in a)`?

Comment: Yeah, that one.

Comment: `getline` reads the next line so if the file is like in the sample, it will only process `>` starting records.

Comment: There could be more than one line between `>` lines and typically they are rather long. Unfortunately these bio people tend to assume that everyone is familiar with FASTA format.